# Parsing amazon s3 log files (PHP)

Tags: php, file, parsing, logging, amazon-s3

I'm looking to parse the amazon s3 log files which are space delimited. Only problem is, some of the space delimited fields contain spaces.  How would I go about parsing a file like this?

```
450227804f8fd31c931036b020ddd0003a03b421d8c669d8858c7c15d72c renderd [10/Apr/2014:19:32:23 +0000] 75.256.56.200 450227804f8fd31c931036b020000343afa03b421d8c669d8858c7c15d72c 0231400AA3D3533C REST.GET.OBJECT Trailer.mp4 "GET /Trailer.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJFV33YRQMN63AQCQ&Expires=1397159234&Signature=8ipN9ymsB5gCzxChTu9lD6ZMrdA%3D HTTP/1.1" 206 - 5016183 16149754 216682 39 "http://example.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36" -
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could probably use a regular expression to parse the log file to get the various parts

Here is an example in PHP to do that

```
<?php 
$string ='450227804f8fd31c931036b020ddd0003a03b421d8c669d8858c7c15d72c renderd [10/Apr/2014:19:32:23 +0000] 75.256.56.200 450227804f8fd31c931036b020000343afa03b421d8c669d8858c7c15d72c 0231400AA3D3533C REST.GET.OBJECT Trailer.mp4 "GET /Trailer.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJFV33YRQMN63AQCQ&Expires=1397159234&Signature=8ipN9ymsB5gCzxChTu9lD6ZMrdA%3D HTTP/1.1" 206 - 5016183 16149754 216682 39 "http://example.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36" -';

$pattern = '/(?P<owner>\S+) (?P<bucket>\S+) (?P<time>\[[^]]*\]) (?P<ip>\S+) (?P<requester>\S+) (?P<reqid>\S+) (?P<operation>\S+) (?P<key>\S+) (?P<request>"[^"]*") (?P<status>\S+) (?P<error>\S+) (?P<bytes>\S+) (?P<size>\S+) (?P<totaltime>\S+) (?P<turnaround>\S+) (?P<referrer>"[^"]*") (?P<useragent>"[^"]*") (?P<version>\S)/';

preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

I slightly modified the answer to Jeremy Quinton to make matched better

```
  <?php 
  $string ='450227804f8fd31c931036b020ddd0003a03b421d8c669d8858c7c15d72c renderd [10/Apr/2014:19:32:23 +0000] 75.256.56.200 450227804f8fd31c931036b020000343afa03b421d8c669d8858c7c15d72c 0231400AA3D3533C REST.GET.OBJECT Trailer.mp4 "GET /Trailer.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJFV33YRQMN63AQCQ&Expires=1397159234&Signature=8ipN9ymsB5gCzxChTu9lD6ZMrdA%3D HTTP/1.1" 206 - 5016183 16149754 216682 39 "http://example.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36" -';

  $pattern = '/(?P<owner>\S+) (?P<bucket>\S+) \[(?P<time>[^]]*)\] (?P<ip>\S+) (?P<requester>\S+) (?P<reqid>\S+) (?P<operation>\S+) (?P<key>\S+) "(?P<method>[^ ]*) (?P<path>[^"]*)" (?P<status>\S+) (?P<error>\S+) (?P<bytes>\S+) (?P<size>\S+) (?P<totaltime>\S+) (?P<turnaround>\S+) "(?P<referrer>[^"]*)" "(?P<useragent>[^"]*)" (?P<version>\S)/';

  preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
  print_r($matches);

  ?>

  result : 
  Array
  (
      [0] => 450227804f8fd31c931036b020ddd0003a03b421d8c669d8858c7c15d72c renderd [10/Apr/2014:19:32:23 +0000] 75.256.56.200 450227804f8fd31c931036b020000343afa03b421d8c669d8858c7c15d72c 0231400AA3D3533C REST.GET.OBJECT Trailer.mp4 "GET /Trailer.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJFV33YRQMN63AQCQ&Expires=1397159234&Signature=8ipN9ymsB5gCzxChTu9lD6ZMrdA%3D HTTP/1.1" 206 - 5016183 16149754 216682 39 "http://example.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36" -
      [owner] => 450227804f8fd31c931036b020ddd0003a03b421d8c669d8858c7c15d72c
      [1] => 450227804f8fd31c931036b020ddd0003a03b421d8c669d8858c7c15d72c
      [bucket] => renderd
      [2] => renderd
      [time] => 10/Apr/2014:19:32:23 +0000
      [3] => 10/Apr/2014:19:32:23 +0000
      [ip] => 75.256.56.200
      [4] => 75.256.56.200
      [requester] => 450227804f8fd31c931036b020000343afa03b421d8c669d8858c7c15d72c
      [5] => 450227804f8fd31c931036b020000343afa03b421d8c669d8858c7c15d72c
      [reqid] => 0231400AA3D3533C
      [6] => 0231400AA3D3533C
      [operation] => REST.GET.OBJECT
      [7] => REST.GET.OBJECT
      [key] => Trailer.mp4
      [8] => Trailer.mp4
      [method] => GET
      [9] => GET
      [path] => /Trailer.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJFV33YRQMN63AQCQ&Expires=1397159234&Signature=8ipN9ymsB5gCzxChTu9lD6ZMrdA%3D HTTP/1.1
      [10] => /Trailer.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJFV33YRQMN63AQCQ&Expires=1397159234&Signature=8ipN9ymsB5gCzxChTu9lD6ZMrdA%3D HTTP/1.1
      [status] => 206
      [11] => 206
      [error] => -
      [12] => -
      [bytes] => 5016183
      [13] => 5016183
      [size] => 16149754
      [14] => 16149754
      [totaltime] => 216682
      [15] => 216682
      [turnaround] => 39
      [16] => 39
      [referrer] => http://example.com
      [17] => http://example.com
      [useragent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36
      [18] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36
      [version] => -
      [19] => -
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Amazon have appended more fields to the log now so this is a new Regex that includes the new fields:

- hostid
- sigversion
- ciphersuite
- authtype
- hostheader
- tlsversion

There are some other changes too:

- The last Regex by Yi did not match a log row at all if the *method+path*, *referrer* or *useragent* values were not surrounded by quotes which is often the case if the values are empty (which is recorded as a single dash).
- The *path* now has the HTTP protocol version appended on the end, so I have separated this off into a new *protocol* value.

**Updated Regex**

```php
$pattern = '/(?P<owner>\S+) (?P<bucket>\S+) \[(?P<time>[^]]*)\] (?P<ip>\S+) (?P<requester>\S+) (?P<reqid>\S+) (?P<operation>\S+) (?P<key>\S+) (-|"-"|"(?P<method>[^ ]*) (?P<path>\S+) (?P<protocol>[^"]*)") (?P<status>\S+) (?P<error>\S+) (?P<bytes>\S+) (?P<size>\S+) (?P<totaltime>\S+) (?P<turnaround>\S+) (-|"(?P<referrer>[^"]*)") (-|"(?P<useragent>[^"]*)") (?P<version>\S+) (?P<hostid>\S+) (?P<sigversion>\S+) (?P<ciphersuite>\S+) (?P<authtype>\S+) (?P<hostheader>\S+) (?P<tlsversion>\S+)/';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
```

You can replace the empty values (dashes) and filter out the duplicate numeric indices from the $matches array like so:

```php
$matches = array_map(
    function($val) { return $val === '-' ? '' : $val; },
    array_filter(
        $matches,
        function($key) { return !is_numeric($key); },
        ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
    )
);
```